# Google Contacts Birthdays Not Updating Google Calendar

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-calendar-api

I've logged in google and I'm trying to get my google contacts birthdays to show up in google calendar.  I am subscribed to the my contacts birthday calendar but I cannot get their birthdays to show in the calendar.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Contacts birthdays are automatically added to your calendar(based on g+ data). Open calendar->Mycalendar->Birthdays->birthdays are displayed if any are there in that month..

Comment: I have one account where the peoples birthdays (as entered in contacts) are added to the calendar but this one doesn't for some reason.  I've tried opening calendar->Mycalendar->Birthdays->birthdays and it is enabled to show.  If it is based on g+ data, why does one calendar display birthdays when the people don't actually have a g+ account??  Am I missing settings somewhere?

Comment: Contact birthdays means both g+ and contacts in gmail..

Comment: Was this resolved ? I do see same problem now

Comment: Internet services related not programming

Answer (score 2):

It may be an issue with the birthday format.

One contact's birthday wasn't showing in google calendar because the birthday was saved in contacts as 15.10.2015 (German date format).
Changing it to October 15, 2015 resolved the issue.